# Cannot open database “” requested by the login. SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm using following database connect to sql server 2014.

```
private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://xx.x.xx.xxx:1433; databaseName=dbName";
private static final String USERNAME = "username";
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("DB Connection failed: " + ex);
    }
    return conn;
```

But it gives following error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database  requested by the login. The login failed.
```

MSSQl queries are correctly executing when in editor. Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure `username` is an SQL Server user (and not an Active Directory user) and that you are using the right password? I also suggest looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the **DB_URL** line, try to replace "**databaseName**" property with "**database**" instead. Which gives :

```
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://xx.x.xx.xxx:1433; database=dbName";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Then maybe try putting the dbName directly after the MSSQL port, like this : private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://xx.x.xx.xxx:1433/dbName;";

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the actual connection code you're using ? Besides, do you have access to the MSSQL server logs to see if a JDBC connection was tried from your java app, and what error message it triggers on the server ? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the post by adding how i get the db connection. sorry I don't have a access to mssql server logs

Comment: Code seems fine. What is weird in the SqlServerException you're getting is that the database name is not given, ie "Cannot open database  requested by the login.", while there should be the database name between words "database" and "requested". I'm pretty sure the connection is not made to the correct database. Taken from example code in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378956%28v=sql.110%29.aspx , try to remove the space between "1433;" and "database" in your DB_URL string variable. Like this : private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://xx.x.xx.xxx:1433;database=dbName"

Comment: Also be sure to restart the java/web app since the String vars are static, thus loaded only once, at class loading time.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://xx.x.xx.xxx:1433/dbName";
String sqlLogin = "root";
String sqlPassword = "";
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, sqlLogin, sqlPassword);
```

Comment: are you sure about your username and your password ? because I use the same code actually and it's work for me

Comment: I used same for login, sqlLogin and password, sqlPassword. I only have  sql Authentication. What should I exactly need to use login and password?

Comment: it was a mistake sorry, use only sqlLogin and sqlPassword but change tue value by your value

Comment: Except for using a different driver and database, this does nothing else than the code in the question.